# KendoUI template para numeros

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, kendoui

Buenas Estoy haciendo cambios en Editor `Number` que trae `KendoUI` para `Asp.net MVC` pero no logro que estos se reflejen en las vistas, las propiedades son de tipo `int`, inclusive puse solo un `H1` solo con una leyenda y aun asi me aparece el control de kendo normal

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El nombre de los templates debe coincidir con el nombre del tipo de dato para que `Razor` al momento de solicitar el `EditorFor` logre utilizarlo en el caso de `int` para este se debe utilizar el nombre 'Int32' o 'Integer' como nombre de la vista